# Не могу собрать проект через консольный maven

Tags: java

Есть проект с вот такими настройками по сборке:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>supermega</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Когда я собираю проект с `IntelliJ Idea`, кликая на `Plugins->assembly->assembly:single`, то все ок. Но когда я захожу в папку с проектом, ввожу команду `mvn assembly:single`, то все прекрасно собирается, но вот при попытке запуска возникает ошибка:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.Main
```

Никак не могу понять куда пропадает класс `Main` при сборке через консоль.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, теперь в нем видно код, проверьте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавь в pom плагин ниже, пересобери и проверь

```
<plugin>  
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>3.0.2</version>     
    <configuration>     
      <archive>     
        <manifest>    
          <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass> <!-- тут правильный путь укажи -->     
        </manifest>    
      </archive>    
  </configuration>   
</plugin>
```

Comment: А разве это не оно ? ` <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>`

Comment: я имею в виду, что добавляется ли в сам файла манифеста класс ?

Comment: Как это можно проверить ?

Comment: открыть jar файл архиватором и посмотреть что прописано в META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Привет. Похоже, у вас не получилось отформатировать xml так, чтобы он нормально отображался  в вопросе. Я поправил форматирование, достаточно было четырёх пробелов перед каждой строкой кода (это разметка Markdown).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да спасибо, не привычно пока

Comment: @keekkenen если будет нужна помощь по форматированию, [читайте справку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) или [приходите в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) за советом